Problem on the cardinality of subgraphs of a bipartite graph
In a bipartite graph with parts
$U$ and
$V$, $|U|=12$.

For any $8$ vertices in $U$, there are exactly $16$ vertices in $V$ connected to at least one of them.
For any $10$ vertices in $U$, there are exactly $20$ vertices in $V$ connected to at least one of them.
There are exactly $n$ vertices in $V$ connected to at least one of vertices in $U$.

I was  asked to prove that $n=24$.
I can prove $n≤24$: Let $U=U_1∪U_2,|U_1|=|U_2|=10$. Then $|U_1∩U_2|=10+10-12=8$. By hypothesis

there are exactly $20$ vertices in $V$ connected to at least one of vertices in $U_1$
there are exactly $20$ vertices in $V$ connected to at least one of vertices in $U_2$
there are exactly $16$ vertices in $V$ connected to at least one of vertices in $U_1∩U_2$

so there are at most $20+20-16=24$ vertices in $V$ connected to at least one of vertices in $U=U_1∪U_2$.
My question is about $n≥24$.?

Not sure, but you may try to assume $n \leq 23$ and show some nodes appear in too many sets and then try to find contradictions.

Let's first assume that the neighbourhood of $U$ (denoted $N(U)$) is actually $V$, otherwise the statement just does not hold. Now pick any two vertices $v,w\in U$ and call $X := \{v,w\}$. We will show that $|N(X)| = 4$, from where the desired result is quickly reached.
( $|N(X)| \geq 4$ ):
Take an arbitrary $Y \subset U\setminus X$ with $|Y| = 8$. Then $|N(Y)| = 16$ and $|N(X\cup Y)| = 20$ which gives $|N(X)| \geq 4$.
($|N(X)| \leq 4$):
This direction is a bit harder. Observe that any two element set $X'$ fulfills the following:
$$
|N(X') \setminus N(Y)| \geq 4 \; \forall Y \subseteq U \setminus X', |Y| \leq 8.
$$
This follows directly from submodularity of the neighbourhood function and the fact that the reduced value of every two element set is known to be $4$ respective to any disjoint set of cardinality $8$.
If this does not make you happy, it can also be seen by purely combinatorial means, but this is left as an exercise for the reader.
This now allows us to construct some lower bound on the size of neighbourhoods of $8$-element sets containing $X$. Pick $3$ disjoint two-element sets from $U \setminus X$, say $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$. and write $A := X\cup \bigcup_i Y_i$. We obtain:
$$
16 = |N(A)| = |N(X)| + |N(Y_1) \setminus N(X)| + |N(Y_2) \setminus N(X\cup Y_1)| + |N(Y_2) \setminus N(X\cup Y_1\cup Y_2)| \geq |N(X)| + 3\cdot 4
$$
Thus we have $|N(X)| = 4$ for any two-element $X$. But if this is true the neighbourhoods of these two-element sets must actually be disjoint since otherwise we could find an $8$-element set with fewer than $4 \cdot (8/2)$ neighbours. Hence we obtain that $|N(U)| = 24$. In fact we recover the exact graph up to isomorphism.

This proof actually seems to show some more general criterion for the modularity of submodular functions, however I am insufficiently into submodular functions to know how much of a thing that is.
